# htaccess help catch all 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have been looking at the webmaster tools this morning, and I have quite a few crawl errors, and old SEO agency seems to have done to some shoddy work to build up my links into the site, but this is resulting in crawl errors,

I would like to 301 redirect any URLS that have /old in them back to my homepage, is that at all possible?

Comment: Please give 1 or 2 examples of such URLs (the more the better) if you want more precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
Redirect permanent */old http://<yourhomepage>
```